# How to hide the details tag without summary tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, css-selectors

I want to hide the details tag without summary, In my code summary is not visible for one condition[as isvisible==false]. So when summary is not visible then the details keyword is visible but I want to hide that too.
I tried to find solutions but i can't get any solutions without using summary tag.

[image: I want to hide the Details keyword and icon]

```
<template>
<details>
    <summary v-if="!isvisible">Hello everyone</summary>
</deatils>
<template>
<script>
export default{
    data(){
        return{
            isvisible: true,
            }
    }
}
</script>
<style>
details > summary {
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

details > summary::-webkit-details-marker {
  display: none;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the open attribute to show the content of the `<details>` element by default and use `v-show` to conditionally display the `<summary>`.

```
<details open>
    <summary v-show="!isvisible">Hello everyone</summary>
    Content
</details>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I'll write v-if condition in details tag then when isvisible== true then also total body inside details tag is removed.

Comment: @user18286913 You can try something like this: `<details open><summary v-show="!isvisible">Hello everyone</summary>Content</details>`

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Can you make it as a solution? then I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

The closest you could get is the :empty pseudoclass:

```
details:empty {
  display: none;
}
```

Although this will only work if the summary element doesn't exist, so would require markup changes.